# Use MySQL in command prompt, ERROR 1064 (42000) occur when creating table

Tags: mysql, xampp, command, create-table

I am using xampp.

After creating a database

```
CREATE DATABASE University + use University
```

I create table by typing

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    SNo INT NOT NULL,
    SName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    SAge INT NOT NULL,
    SDepartment ENUM('CS', 'EE', 'Math', 'Physics') NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (SNo) 
);
```

But a beep is resulted and

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use University 
CREATE TABLE Student
(    
    SNo INT NOT NULL,
    Sname VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    SAg'
at line 2
```

is shown in command prompt. But I don't know what the syntax error is in this case.

Comment: Are you doing this as one script?  I see no semicolon after creating the database, and I've never seen that syntax before.  make the Create on one line, the Use on another, and then try to create the table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `+` is giving you syntax error. Try getting rid of it to separate these into two statements

```
CREATE DATABASE University
USE University
```

Comment: I think this is right. The CREATE statement works fine when I tried it